# How to loop this array and save to database?

Tags: php, foreach

I have this array to save to database:

```
{"i_barcode_id":["3","3"],"i_barcode_sn":["8999999565404","6933412700043"]}
```

how do I save it to DB so the databse should be like this.

```
i_barcode_id     i_barcode_sn
3                8999999565404
3                6933412700043
```

this is my current script.

```
foreach($myarray as $row){          
        
        $dataadd_sto_d  = array (                           
            'ID' => $rows['i_barcode_id'],
            'SN' => $rows['i_barcode_sn']
        );
        
        $insertsto_d    = $this->MWarehouse->add_sto_d($dataadd_sto_d); //insert script
        
};
```

The script failed to save to database. I do not know why. any

Comment: The data structure you want to save looks like a JSON object rather than a PHP associative array.

Comment: I agree with Martin. Could you post a more complete example of your code?

Comment: I receive that array from an API and need to save it to database. I can't show any other than that.

Answer (score 0):

Use this tested working

```
$key = array();
$value = array();
foreach($myarray as $row){                                  
   $id => $rows['i_barcode_id'],
   $sn => $rows['i_barcode_sn']
    array_push($key, $id);
    array_push($value, $sn);
}
$insert_data = array_combine($key, $value);  
return $this->MWarehouse->add_sto_d($insert_data);
```

**Note**
array_combine() will now throw a ValueError if the numberof elements for each array is not equal; previously this function returned false instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in your Code like `foreach(... as $row)` and later you want to access `$rows`

My Attemp would be, to grap `i_barcode_id` or `i_barcode_sn` to loop and take the value index to get the data from the other array.
Example:

```
//true at the end, cause i have something against stdClass without any reason
$myarray = json_decode('{"i_barcode_id":["3","3"],"i_barcode_sn":["8999999565404","6933412700043"]}',true);

foreach($myarray['i_barcode_id'] as $key => $val){
    $insertArray=array(
        "ID" => $val,
        "SN"=>$myarray['i_barcode_sn'][$key]
    );
    //Your Insert Script
};
```